# Live filtering within Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets

Is it possible to have filtered data update automatically as values change in rows in Google Sheets?

Say I have 10 rows of data, where one column holds only `TRUE/FALSE` values, based on a formula. I can use a filter on that column say "show me only rows with `TRUE` values", and it works.

However, if I change a value elsewhere in the spreadsheet, causing the `TRUE/FALSE` values to change, the filter is not dynamically re-applied. Some `TRUE` rows change to `FALSE`, but aren't hidden; some `FALSE` rows change to `TRUE`, but are not shown.

How can I make a table of data dynamically change what is shown when I edit a value in another cell?

(I'm happy to use [`FILTER()`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093197?hl=en) if that helps, but I can't figure out exactly how to use it.)

---

*To avoid an [XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem), my goal here is to have one column holding a whitespace-delimited set of "tags" for the row, and another cell (outside the table) where you can type in a tag and see the table automatically filtered to show only rows including that tag. Right now I can accomplish this goal of filtering by using "Filter by condition/custom formula is" along with with `REGEXMATCHES()` with a formula that composes a regex from another cell, and it works correctly each time I 'touch' the filter criteria...but changing the cell outside the table does not cause the filter formula to be re-applied.*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would use the `=filter()` function as follows: on another sheet, enter

```
=filter(Sheet1!A:Z, Sheet1!C:C = True)
```

where it is assumed that the sheet with original data is Sheet1, the data is in columns A-Z, and the column with True/False values is column C.